# What type of lens mount is this SOM Berthiot?

Tags: lens-mount, old-lenses

I bought this SOM Berthiot 20mm f1.9 lens assuming it was a c-mount, but it is much smaller with an elongated screw mount. Can't figure out what type of mount this could be.

[image: Som2]

Here it is compared to a regular c-mount lens:

[image: Som1]

Comment: Thanks...I can't find any info on Lytar5.5mm however...anyone else have anything to add?

Comment: I believe this to be a lens for a Bolex 16mm format motion film camera.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolex

Comment: Thanks, yes i think you are right.  I'm thinking also possibly for 8mm or 9.5mm Bolex. It's just so strange that I cannot find any pics of similar mount anywhere. Thanks all.

Comment: [Google Images: Paillard Kern Bolex Lens mount](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=Paillard+Kern+Bolex+Lens+mount)

Answer (score 3):

The lens in the picture is either a [Bolex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolex) 8mm/9.5mm or 16mm format motion film camera.

Comment: I agree, I have the same type of lenses for a 16mm camera (Pathé Webo) only the ones of the 16mm camera are a C mount. These also seem to be a D mount perhaps? Perhaps they can be mounted on a modern DSLR?

Answer (score 2):

This is a French cine lens. Monsieur Berthiot workshop. Society Optical Mechanical is my translation of SOM.

It is definitely not for 16mm. Not for the D mount cameras, but it must be for 8mm or 9.5mm cine. Not for the Swiss Bolexes. It seems to be proprietary to Berthiot and unlikely to fit anything made by anyone else.
20mm would be ~ 115mm in 135 format or FF in recent parlance. So a portrait lens.

Might be convertible to Pentax Q but the registration distance might be an issue. DIY adapter, I an afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Lens is simply missing the back half. It's not a mount, just a broken lens.

Answer (score -1):

It's smaller than 8mm d-mount. Looks like Lytar 5.5mm.

Answer (score -2):

This "auxiliary" type lens screws into the front of a "standard" lens

Comment: It is? What lens thread would it attach to? If it's an auxiliary lens, why does it have aperture control and an aperture scale, as well as a focus distance scale?